# Multiple zclip functions - only the last one works

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

I'm using the "zclip" jquery function to perform a cross-browser copy-to-clipboard, when a user clicks on a button.

However, as soon as I assign the zclip function to yet another button, the first one stops working.

The code is:

```
function setupClipboard(o, i) {

    o.find('.copytext').zclip({
        path: 'js/zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: function() {
            return $('#customtext' + i).val();
        }
    });

}
```

You can see the problem here: http://toolii.com/apps/the-character-counter/
(Watch the console.log in the browser to see what it tries to copy.)

Do any of you have an idea of how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I just had to remove all existing instances of zclip and inserting them again, each time I added a field.